# Access belongs_to on a Mongoid::Document subclass

Tags: mongoid, has-many, sti

I have a model 'Index' as:

```
class Index
  include Mongoid::Document
  
  belongs_to :project  
end
```

Another model PercentileRankIndex inherits Index

```
class PercentileRankIndex < Index

     def self.model_name
         Index.model_name
     end

end
```

Suppose I do :

```
 p = Index.first (OR EVEN) p = PercentileRankIndex.first
```

I get this :

```
#<PercentileRankIndex _id: 51630ece34b2613d27000011, project_id: "51630ece34b2613d27000010", enabled: true, _type: "PercentileRankIndex", :enabled: "true">
```

However on doing

> p.project
>
> =>nil

The belongs_to relationship isnt working on child class. Why? How can I fix it?